# Named Pipe, Communication between 2 children

Tags: linux

I have a problem with my code. I want to make communication between 2 children process. One of them is a server, which opens a file and sends each letter to the second process. The second process is counting letters and it should make a new file and save results. I have problems with the last step because the first process gonna finish faster than the second, what causes the end of the program. I have no idea how fix it. Looking for some tips :).

Here you got result.

[image]

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

//stale
#define FIFO "my_fifo"
#define SIZE 26

//zmienne globalne
int desk; //deskryptor pliku
int tab[SIZE];

//prototypy funkcji
void parentKillAll();
void server(FILE * file);
void client();
void cleanUp(FILE * file);
int checkEntryData(int argc, char *argv);
void replaceTabWithZero(int * tab);
void countLetters(int * tab, char ch);
void saveResults(int * tab, char *title);
void showTab(int * tab);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (!checkEntryData(argc, argv[1]))
        return 1;

    replaceTabWithZero(tab);
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    umask(0);
    mkfifo(FIFO, 0666);

    if (file) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            server(file);   
            exit(0);
        } else if (fork() == 0) {
            client();
            saveResults(tab, strcat(argv[1], "Result"));
            showTab(tab);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            cleanUp(file);
            parentKillAll();
        }
    } else {
        perror("Error");
    }

    return 0;
}

void parentKillAll() {
    sleep(1);
    kill(0, SIGKILL);
    exit(0);
}

void server(FILE * file) {
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        desk = open(FIFO, O_WRONLY);
        write(desk, &ch, 1);
    }
}

void client() {
    char ch;
    while (1) {
        desk = open(FIFO, O_RDONLY);
        read(desk, &ch, 1);
        countLetters(tab, ch);
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
}

void cleanUp(FILE *file) {
    wait(0);
    fclose(file);
    close(desk);
}

int checkEntryData(int argc, char *argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Nie poprawna ilosc argumentow\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (access(argv, F_OK)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Podany plik \'%s\' nie istnieje\n", argv);
        return 0;
    }

    if (access(argv, R_OK)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Brak uprawnien do odczytu pliku \'%s\'\n", argv);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void replaceTabWithZero(int * tab) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        tab[i] = 0;
}

void countLetters(int *tab, char ch) {
    int chVal = ch;

    if (chVal > 92)
        chVal -= 32;

    if (chVal > 64 && chVal < 91)
        tab[chVal-65] += 1;               
}

void saveResults(int *tab, char * title) {
    FILE *plik = fopen(title, "w");
    if (plik) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            fprintf(plik, "%c - %d\n", (i+97), tab[i]);
    } else {
        perror("Error");
    }

    fclose(plik);
}

void showTab(int * tab) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("\n%d", tab[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that the client process can never finish, because it runs an infinite `while(1)` loop without any exit conditions.

You should rewrite it so that it exits after reading all available data:

```
void client() {
        char ch;
        // Open the fifo only once, instead of once per character
        desk = open(FIFO, O_RDONLY);

        // Loop until there is no more data to read
        while(read(desk, &ch, 1) > 0) {
                countLetters(tab, ch);
                printf("%c", ch);                       
        }       
}
```

This is technically sufficient to make it work, but you should also look into a series of other issues:

- You should have two `wait(0)` calls so that you wait for both processes, and you shouldn't try to kill anything.
- The server process should only be opening the fifo once, not once per character.
- You should be comparing `fgetc` output to EOF *before* forcing the value into a char. Since you do it after, running your program on a ISO-8859-1 terminal will cause it to confuse EOF and the letter `ÿ`
- You are using `strcat` on `argv[1]`, even though you don't know how much space that array has. You should use your own buffer of a known length.
- You should check the return value of all your system calls to ensure they succeed. Checking with `access` and then assuming it'll be fine is not as good since calls can fail for other reasons.
- Canonical Unix behavior is to exit with 0 for success, and >= 1 for error.
- It's good practice to use a larger buffer (e.g. 65536 bytes instead of 1) when using `read`/`write` directly. stdio functions like `fgetc` already uses a larger buffer behind the scenes.
- Using a named pipe obviously works, but since you spawn both processes it would be more natural to use an unnamed one.

Comment: I really want to thanks you. Your answer dissolves all doubts. You not only solved the problem, but also pointed out weak points and give me tips for future. I use named pipe, because I have task at classes and must use it. The teacher didnt describe the subject too closely and gave bad example, which i modeled on. I was looking for examples in books, but I found only fundamental things. One more time thanks you :).